# Algorithm to prevent duplication of field while copying data from text file to excel

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have over 100 text (.txt) files. The data in these files is comma-separated, for example:

```
good,bad,fine
```

The aforementioned items are just an example, the data can contain anything from individual words and email-IDs to phone numbers. I have to copy all of these values into a single column of one or more Excel (.xlsx) spreadsheet files.

Now the problem is that I don't want my data to be redundant and the data items should be over 10 million. I'm planning to implement this design in C++. I prefer an algorithm which is efficient so that I can complete my work fast.

Comment: crore ? what is this word ?

Comment: Sorry I am an Indian. 1 Crore = 10 million

Answer (score 1):

Separate your task into 2 steps:

a. getting the list of items in the memory - removing duplicates.

b. putting them into excel.

---

a: Use a sorted linked tree to gather all items, that's how you will find the duplicate fast.

b: Once done with the list - I would write everything to a simple file and import it to excel, rather than try to do it with c++ against excel API.

After your comment- if a memory problem rise, you might want to create a tree per first letter and - use files to store "each list", so you will not get memory overflow...

it is less efficient, but with today's computing power you won't feel it.

Main idea here is to find fast if you have this word on not and if not - add it to the "list". Searching a sorted tree should do the trick. if you want to avoid worst case scenario there is AVL tree if I recall correctly, this tree will remain even no matter the order of the inserts, yet it is harder to code.

Comment: I am a college sophomore. I haven't studied Linked tree yet..! I know about linked list and doubly linked list. Guess I have to study linked tree first.

Comment: Avl tree is a heavy topic, and no so easy to implement, but there are plenty examples in the web. you need to understand the principals of binary search. Given the 10 mil objects I guess your teacher doesn't want you to use any array for this task so you need to figure another way to hold the data --> a tree is a good option.

Comment: Well it's not a problem given by my teacher. I am working on a project in which i have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way would be to simply load all the values (as std::strings) into an [std::set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/). The interface is dead simple. It won't be the fastest way, but you never know.

In particular unordered_set might be faster if you have it available, but will be harder to use because the large number of strings will cause rehashing if you don't prepare properly.

As you read a string, insert it into the set: `if(my_set.insert("the string").second) ...`. That condition will be true for new values only.

10 million is a lot but if each string is around 20 bytes or so, you may get away with a simplistic approach like this.